# Determinar si el número es primo MATLAB

Tags: matlab, números-primos

Necesito implementar una función que determine si un número entero N es primo o no.

Sabemos que un cierto número se dice primo si es no divisible por cualquier número entre 2 y la raíz cuadrada de N.

En consecuencia, he propuesto el siguiente código:

```
n = input('Escriba un número entero n: ');

a = floor(n); 

i = 2;
while i < a
    if rem(n,i) == 0;
        disp('El número no es primo');
    else
        disp('El número es primo');
    end

i = i+1;
end
```

Sin embargo, el programa no dice si el número es primo o no. Si no que realiza la división y en función del resto imprime en pantalla una cosa u otra.

```
 >> Ej2
Escriba un número entero n: 
12
El número no es primo
El número no es primo
El número no es primo
El número es primo
El número no es primo
El número es primo
El número es primo
El número es primo
El número es primo
El número es primo
>>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el programa pare en el momento en que encuentre un número i cuyo rem sea igual a cero? De este modo, ya sabríamos que no es primo y no haría falta seguir, ni imprimir tantas veces "El número es/no es primo".

Comment: Define una variable bandera como cero. Si se cumple la condición, la pones en 1 y le das `break` pa salir del while. Al salir del while, validas si la variable es 1 o 0 y muestras el mensaje que necesites.

Comment: agregá un break dentro del if, luego, "el numero es primo" tenes que mostrarlo si termina el while (si a==i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución al problema, la publico por si alguna persona la requiere en algún futuro:

```
function es_primo = esPrimo(numero)
% Verifica si un número es primo o no

es_primo = true; % Suponemos que el número es primo hasta demostrar lo contrario

if numero <= 1
    es_primo = false; % Si el número es 1 o menor, no es primo
    return;
end

for i = 2:sqrt(numero)
    if mod(numero, i) == 0
        es_primo = false; % Si el número es divisible por algún número entre 2 y su raíz cuadrada, no es primo
        return;
    end
end

end
```

Este código define una función esPrimo que recibe un número como entrada y devuelve true si es primo y false si no lo es. El algoritmo para determinar si un número es primo consiste en dividirlo por todos los números enteros entre 2 y su raíz cuadrada, y si no es divisible por ninguno de ellos, entonces es primo. La función utiliza una sentencia for para iterar sobre los números enteros entre 2 y la raíz cuadrada del número, y la función mod para determinar si el número es divisible por cada uno de ellos. Si el número es divisible por alguno de estos números, entonces la función devuelve false indicando que el número no es primo.